# Oracle 12c auto increment

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

So I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE car (
  id                                NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY, 
  (...)
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Then I've added a new column:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE car_sequence START WITH 1;
ALTER TABLE car ADD id_internal NUMBER DEFAULT car_sequence.nextval NOT NULL;
```

How can I force auto increment for `id_internal` (on insert) based on the next value from the `car_sequence` ? Is a trigger the only way out here ?

Comment: Again, what you've shown works in both 12cR1 and 12cR2. What problem are you having with it?

Comment: Aforementioned statements work. But when I try to insert a new row I am getting: `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("car"."id_internal")`.

Comment: Insert works fine for me too, only supply a value for an extra column - not for `id` or `id_internal`. Which version and patch level are you on? I suppose it's feasible there were issues with this in the base 12cR1 release...

Comment: ok, I believe it's hibernate problem because when I did what you said - provide a value only for an extra column - it worked. So I have to deal with hibernate to solve it. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I try to insert a new row I am getting: `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("car"."id_internal")`

This seems to be [bug 18110491](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=18110491.8), which affects 12.1.0.1 and 12.1.0.2. It's reported as fixed in the October 2017 PSU (and in 12cR2), so - assuming you have a support contract, without which you won't be able to see the bug report anyway - you can apply that (or a later one). This is working fine for me in my 12cR1 system, with a more recent PSU.